# Python OpenCV - executing multiple commandline scripts on same image file

Tags: python, opencv3.0

Attempting to pass the path of saved imaged through stdout from one command line process to another.  Image doesn't close until entire script is complete. "rotate" saves to path1.rotated.png
"myCrop" uses path1.rotated.png as input "myCrop" errors with empty image. everything works if I execute individually manually through command line

```
import glob
import os
import ntpath
import random
import sys
import random
import math
import json
import cv2
import subprocess
import re
import datetime as dt
from collections import defaultdict


def rotate(fn):    
#rotate    
    try:
        p = subprocess.run(['python','rotate.py','-i',fn], 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
        fn = p.stdout.decode()
        return p.stdout.decode()      
    except:
        print('could not rotate ',fn, p.stderr.decode())


def crop(fn):
#crop   
    fn = fn.replace('\\','\\\\') 
    try:
        print(fn)        
        print('cropping',fn)
        p = subprocess.run(['python','myCrop.py','-i',fn], 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0) 
        fn = p.stdout.decode()
        return p.stdout.decode()
    except:
        print('could not crop ',fn)

def process_image(o, f):
    fn = o + "\\" + f
    rotated = rotate(fn)
    print("rotated as :",rotated)
    cropped = crop(rotated)
    print("cropped as :", cropped)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = open(str(dt.datetime.now()).replace(":","-") + '.results.txt','w')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and '*' in sys.argv[1]:
        files = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
        random.shuffle(files)
    else:
    files = sys.argv[1:]

for path in files:
    #out_path = path.replace('.jpg', '.crop.png')
    dirName  = os.path.dirname(path) # + '\\modified\\' 
    fileName = os.path.basename(path)
    #fileName = fileName.replace('.png', '.modified.png') 
    #out_path = dirName + fileName # .png as input
    #newImagePath = path.replace(".png", ".modified.png")
    #if os.path.exists(out_path): continue
    try:
        process_image(dirName,fileName)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s %s' % (path, e))
    fn.close()
```

Comment: Please point out the actual probem in more detail.

Comment: pass in image name on command line.  The code properly runs through the first call to "rotate", passes the path to the created file as text to "crop", but the image file has not closed.  "crop" opens an empty file and gets error due to image having height and width of zero.  When the entire code completes the image is then closed.  How can I get the image to close at the end of "rotate"?